# How to handle exception inside an EventListener class in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

On the onRegistrationSuccess method of an EventListener class, I have an api call that registers a user into another system.

```
$response = $this->service->postCustomer($customer)

if (200 !== $response->getCode() {
   $response = new RedirectResponse($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo());
   $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to catch the error or display it on the same page? example the route is on `/user/register` the response is a validation error. Cause right now it still redirects the use to the check email page.

Btw im using FOSUserBundle. Im really new in Symfony so im really not aware on what's the best way to do it

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use flash messages `$session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Validation error');`. Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, @MohamedRadhiGuennichi but I also wanted to know if I'm the right event, it should halt the registration process, but currently it does go thru and still shows the check your email page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the priority of your listener as described [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html#registration-success-listener-with-enabled-confirmation-at-the-same-time), otherwise the listener responsible for email confirmation page fires earlier

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
            ['onRegistrationSuccess', 10],
        ],
    ];
}
```

You can use flash messages to show the error as was suggested by @MohamedRadhiGuennichi

Subscribing to `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` means that the user is already stored in your database, so you should rollback this in case of an error.

Comment: Thank you Artur, but is there any chance to show me on how to roll it back in case there's an error? cause yes it did stored data into the database

Comment: You can't use db transactions here, so I guess you just have to remove user from the db in case of an API error. This should be considered an edge case, and your app should do its best validating the data before sending to the external API.
I would probably synchronize data using a cron command, this way customers still would be able to sign up even in case of API outage, and I would be able to sync them later